# Recursive descent parser first and follow

Tags: parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, compilation, recursive-descent

to implement a recursive descent parser is the first and follow sets required? and if so can you still build the recursive descent given non uniqueness in the first and follows?
I'm having a hard time distinguishing between recursive descent and ll(1) parsing.

Thanks.

Comment: FIRST and FOLLOW sets are required by LR parser *generators*. Parsers themselves don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive descent parsers do not have to be deterministic, i.e. one can construct recursive descent parsers that cannot decide which derivation to choose after a finite constant lookahead.

LL(k) parsers construct a parse tree incrementally, each new character will extend the parse tree.

Nondetermistic recursive descent parsers can build a parse tree, which is discarded completely on the occurrence of a certain character.

Examples for recursive descent which is not necessarily LL(k):

- Parsing in PROLOG (backtracking)
- Packrat Parsing (backtracking with memoization)